# Array data push inside knockout utils foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, foreach

I'm using Knockout Utils Foreach array for loop through a json and now I want to add a new items to each array objects.

Following is my code:

```
var self = this;
        self._isVisible = ko.observable(false);
        dc.manager.executeQuery(actionQuery).then(function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.results, function (item) {
                item.push(self._isVisible);
            });
            items(data.results);
        }).fail(function (error) {});
```

But when I run this, I got the following error:

```
Error : Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
```

I tried to find other solutions to fix this error. But still no luck. Can anyone help for me on this error

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that item is an array? Could you post structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense to me  :

```
item.push(self._isVisible);
```

I think what you want to do is more something like that  :

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.results, function (item) {
    item._isVisible = true;
});
```

Could you explain what want to do ?